# R code equivalent to: "if x is part of the data.frame y", then return z"

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am new to R, and I had no clue how I could google this, hence I am asking here. 
Any help will be appreciated!

I am wondering how I can transform the below into a code:

If {x (a character) is part of the data.frame y, then return A}
else
{return B}

```
y <- data.frame(A = c("dog", "cat", "bear", "zebra"), 
                B = c("mosquito", "cockroach", "fly", "worm")

A <- "a_word"
```

In the above dataset, I would like to say for instance:

```
If { 
"dog" is part of y$A, then 
return the A
} 

else if{
"dog" is part of y$B, then 
return B
}
```

That "if x is part of the data.frame" part is the one that I am struggling with. Since x is not a number, I did not know how to write that as a code in R!
If it was a number, then it would be something like:

```
ifelse(sum(x[i] == y[1:12]) == 1, A, B)
```

How can I do this with a character?

Comment: can you post a sample dataset using `dput(y)` and pasting the output into your question?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could paste the output because I did not know how to code for it in the first place. However, I did make the example more specific. Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by B or A? You want the entire column or just the corresponding value? In this case "dog"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `%in%`.

In the following code I check wether `"dog"` is in column `A` then if it is column `B`. `x` is the return value.

```
y <- data.frame(A = c("dog", "cat", "bear", "zebra"), 
                B = c("mosquito", "cockroach", "fly", "worm")

A <- "a_word"
B <- "b_word"
C <- "c_word"

if ("dog" %in% y$A) {
   x <- A
} else if ("dog" %in% y$B) {
   x <- B
} else {
  x <- C
}
x
```